# How transform raw mysql to laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-4

I need your help.
I have tried to transform this mysql into the laravel, but I will get an "Cannot call xy function on a non-object".

This is the mysql query, which is run on mysql without any errors:

```
select k.id, users.email, problemsets.name, k.created_at, k.state as state, k.id as link
FROM ( SELECT * FROM  `user_practicesets` AS b ORDER BY b.id DESC ) AS k

 left join `users` on `users`.`id` = k.`id_user`
 left join `practicesets` on `practicesets`.`id` = k.`id_practiceset`
 left join `problemsets` on `problemsets`.`practiceset_id` = `practicesets`.`id`
GROUP BY k.id_user, k.id_practiceset
 order by k.`id_practiceset`
```

This is my transformation:

```
 $items = DB::select(
DB::raw('select k.id, users.email, problemsets.name, k.created_at, k.state as state, k.id as link '.
'FROM ( SELECT * FROM  `user_practicesets` AS b ORDER BY b.id DESC ) AS k '.
'left join `users` on `users`.`id` = k.`id_user` '.
'left join `practicesets` on `practicesets`.`id` = k.`id_practiceset` '.
'left join `problemsets` on `problemsets`.`practiceset_id` = `practicesets`.`id` '.
'GROUP BY k.id_user, k.id_practiceset '.
'order by k.`id_practiceset`'
))->get();


            return Datatables::of($items)
                ->edit_column('state', '{{ $state == 1 ? "<span class=\"text-success glyphicon glyphicon-ok\"></span>" : "<span class=\" text-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove\"></span>" }}')
                ->edit_column('link', '<button data-id="{{$id}}" type="button" class="view-up btn btn-sm btn-primary">Megtekint</button>')
                ->make();
```

I have no any idea unfortunately.

The `$items` has the following data:

```
Array (
 [0] => stdClass Object (
   [id] => 25 
   [email] => test@gmail.com 
   [name] => Test name 
   [created_at] => 2015-04-08 17:12:31
   [state] => 0 
   [link] => 25 
) )
```

Comment: Does $items actually contain data?

Comment: Yes. This is in:
`Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 25
            [email] => test@gmail.com
            [name] => Test name
            [created_at] => 2015-04-08 17:12:31
            [state] => 0
            [link] => 25
        )

)`

Comment: That's a pretty heavy-duty query there. Does a smaller, less complicated one work as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, my experience with datatables is that you should not use `->get()`, you should pass the `QueryBuilder` object, not the `Collection` to it.

Secondly, what difference does your FROM clause with the order have compared to a 'normal'

```
FROM `user_practicesets`
```

?

If you want the highest id, just use a max(id) in your select, it will make your life easier I guess. Not sure what you are expecting really, so you should probably tweak it here and there.

Anyay, you probably want to end up with something like (untested):

```
$items = DB::table('user_practicesets')::with('users')
    ->with('practiceSets')
    ->with('problemSets')
    ->select(
        DB::raw('MAX(user_practicesets.id) as link'),
        'users.email',
        'problemsets.name',
        'user_practicesets.created_at',
        'user_practicesets.state'
    )
    ->groupBy('user_practicesets.id_user', 'user_practicesets.id_practiceset')
    ->orderBy('user_practicesets.id_practiceset');
```

But for this you have to have your relations setup. You could also add the joins yourself, by replacing the with (eager loading) with `->leftJoin()` and do it yourself.

One thing, if you want Laravel (and Eloquent) to make things easier for you, stick to the naming conventions when creating your tables and fields. You're using both `id_practiceset` and `practiceset_id`, that's a) confusing, and b) `id_practiceset` will not be resolved automagically. You could of course set foreign keys in your relations, but it's unnecessary really.

Answer (score 0):

With laravel, it is better to use its ready-to-use relationships. It creates the required joins automatically.
Please, check this part of documentation, [Querying Relations](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations).